# Finding an IC without really understanding the numbers

Tags: voltage-regulator

First of all, this is only about learning & seeing if I can revive a tablet.

I have an Onn tablet that even tho it is a few years old has only been used less then 5 hours. The battery was flat which I expected. I hooked it up to a charger and it draws .09 amps at 5 volts. So I pulled the battery and charged it slowly then plugged back in. I noticed the board was warm so I started testing it and removed a cap I found grounded but the pad was still grounded. Looking under the microscope, an IC had a dot on it and I touched it before trying to read it. It is likely the numbers were already burnt off, but I will never know now.

There is another power circuit beside of it I hope is the same but I can not find these exact markings.

[image: LPS 1e9c1]

[image]

Here are two pictures of the board. Please let me know what you want me to get a close up of. Beside of "1" is the bad IC & by "2" is the one I can read the markings. There is an error pointing at the cap I removed.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did the IC just...explode like that?  If so, there are almost certainly other broken components on the board. Regardless, we will need far more information: detailed, in focus pictures of the circuitry surrounding the IC; where the board was warm; what cap you removed and how you decided it was "grounded", etc.

Comment: Please post dimensions

Comment: There was more to the post but I do not know what happened to everything below the second picture.

It was not blown open. I poked at the dot on top of it & it disintegrated.

I tested continuity from ground to both sides of the cap beside of it. Both sides had 0 resistance so I removed the cap to see if the cap was the issue but the pad still had resistance.

I will get measurements.

Comment: 2.9 mm long 
1.5 mm wide
.9 mm tall

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a [Lowpower (微源半导体) LP3987H-33B5F](http://ai.lowpowersemi.com:811/ESAPP1_13.1/201806/L_rc20180623000005_L20180623000044_LP3987H-05.pdf) 3.3V LDO regulator. The datasheet doesn't specify the markings, but other Lowpower parts use this pattern:

```
LPS
PPYWX
```

P: Product code
Y: Year code
W: Week code
X: Series number

I found a picture that shows that the LP3987H-33B5F seems to use the product code `1e`:

[image]

(Source: [lcsc.com](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Linear-Voltage-Regulators-LDO_LOWPOWER-LP3987H-33B5F_C517256.html))

Comment: I got the parts a couple of days ago but I accidentally wiped a couple of resistors off the board & since I do not know the value of them I am afraid this is a lost cause.